# Using List<BaseType> as a field for entity for holding derived entity using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance

Suppose I have an entity, representing recurring event:

```
public class ReccuringEvent : EntityBase, IReccuringEvent
{
    public virtual ICollection<ReccuringElementBase> IncludedElements { get; private set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ReccuringElementBase> ExcludedElements { get; private set; }
}
```

And suppose I have a bunch of entities that derived from ReccuringElementBase (this class hold some shared data for Monthly, Weekly). E.g.:

```
public class ReccuringElementBase
{
    public DateTime _startFrom { get; private set; }
    public DateTime _endBy { get; private set; }
    ...
}

public class Monthly : ReccuringElementBase
{
    public int MonthToPerform { get; private set; }
    ...
}
```

What I want is to hold them (Weekly, Monthly, etc) in List<'ReccuringElementBase> InlcudedElements/ExcludedElements. Entity Framework can handle situations when you explicitly use a derived class as a Property or Property Collection (like  Monthly/Weekly in SomeReccuringRule entity) and map them  in to a database table (using Table Per Hierarchy (TPH), Table Per Type (TPT), Table Per Concrete Class (TPC)):

```
public class SomeReccuringRule : EntityBase
{
    public Monthly { get; private set; }
    public Weekly { get; private set; }
    ...
}
```

However, I have something different. Can Entity Framework map Property of type ICollection<'ReccuringElementBase> (which must hold Monthly, Weekly, etc) to database, and if yes, how it can be implemented?

Comment: "We have something different": what do you have that is different?  Also, I don't understand what you mean by "when you explicitly use a derived class as set as a field".  Finally, your code sample define a class called `RecurringEvent` but then the text never mentions that class.  It does mention `RecurringElementBase` -- is that a mistake, or are they separate classes?

Comment: Thanks. I edited my question. Hope it is clearly now.

Comment: Yes, your question is much clearer now.  I am sorry I do not know the answer.  It seems like it ought to be possible, but I have little experience with EF.